# Gnuplot multiplot with 2 plots stacked over each other

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am having trouble getting a multiplot with gnuplot where two plots are stacked over each other. I came this far with the following code:

```
multiplot> unset xtics
multiplot> set xrange [:108]
multiplot> plot "haildays_north_south.txt" u 0:4 w line lc rgb "blue" t "POH timeseries north", f(x) w line lc rgb "red" t "f(x) = -0.012x+5.27"
multiplot> set xtics ("2002" 1, "2004" 13, "2006" 25, "2008" 37, "2010" 49, "2012" 61, "2014" 73, "2016" 85, "2018" 97, "2020" 108)
multiplot> set xrange [:108]
multiplot> set yrange [:16]
multiplot> set ylab "Number of haildays per month"
multiplot> set xlab "Months (April-September 2002-2019)"
multiplot> plot "haildays_north_south.txt" u 0:3 w line lc rgb "blue" t "POH timeseries south", g(x) w line lc rgb "red" t "f(x) = 0.026x+2.87"
```

[image]

However, I would like the upper plot to have the vertical grid lines too, I need the whole plot as a size .7,.7 and I only want one ylabel centered between both plots if possible. Unfortunately I don´t know in which order I need to call the commands and which exactly.

Help would be gladly appreciated!
Best ,
Lena

Comment: Could you please give a few example lines of your input data? Since you are plotting pseudocolumn 0, I assume that your data is without any timestamp (e.g. like `2002-01 2.1 8 ...`), but just the monthly values after each other starting from January 2002 in column 3.

Comment: About the size... what do you mean with .7,.7? Inches? The whole canvas or only the two graphs together? Which terminal are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding vertical grid lines can be done using the same command as you used already but give blank labels. You may want to suppress the tic marks also:

```
set xtics scale 0.0
set xtics ("" 1, "" 13, "" 25, "" 37, "" 49, "" 61, "" 73, "" 85, "" 97, "" 108)
```

I am not sure I understand the question about placing a y label between the plots.  Did you really mean the x label (i.e. only one copy rather than one under each plot)?  For that you can add `unset xlabel` before the second plot command, and adjust the vertical positioning of the remaining label using the `offset` keyword.

If you really do mean the ylabel, the same method applies.

Revised script:

```
set xrange [:108]
set xtics scale 0.0
set xtics ("" 1, "" 13, "" 25, "" 37, "" 49, "" 61, "" 73, "" 85, "" 97, "" 108)
set xlabel "Months (April-September 2002-2019)" offset 0,-1
plot "haildays_north_south.txt" u 0:4 w line lc rgb "blue" t "POH timeseries north", f(x) w line lc rgb "red" t "f(x) = -0.012x+5.27"
set xtics ("2002" 1, "2004" 13, "2006" 25, "2008" 37, "2010" 49, "2012" 61, "2014" 73, "2016" 85, "2018" 97, "2020" 108)
unset xlabel
set xrange [:108]
set yrange [:16]
set ylabel "Number of haildays per month"
set ylabel left offset 0,10   # left-justified, also shift upwards
plot "haildays_north_south.txt" u 0:3 w line lc rgb "blue" t "POH timeseries south", g(x) w line lc rgb "red" t "f(x) = 0.026x+2.87"
```

~

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Do you know how to set the size of the whole plot to .7,.7, too?

Comment: You can probably use the `scale` and `offset` parameters to `set multiplot layout`.  But I find it difficult to understand how the `offset` works so I can't offer an exact command.